# HTML button on click should hide form if success

Tags: c#, jquery, json, button

I have the following cshtml:

```
using (Html.BeginForm(MVC.ProbleemRapport.ActionNames.Form, MVC.ProbleemRapport.Name, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "probleemForm" }))
    {

                <button type="submit" id="verzendenBtn"  class="btn actie" title="@StartSchermResource.BtnSend">@StartSchermResource.BtnSend</button>
    }
```

I have a jquery that does the following :

```
$('#verzendenBtn').click(function () {

        $('#probleemForm').find('.error').remove();

        // do some validation

        if (value === false) {
            return value;
        }

    });
```

Now when i click my button, the validation works fine.
But when everything is completed and the post happens to the controller, I get a json-result. Which is normal since my action returns a json result containing "true" of "false".

When the result is "true", I need to hide the form.
When the result is "false", I need to hide the form and display a message that something went wrong.

but the only thing that is happening now, is that I get the request to open the json.

What am I forgetting?

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to do `$('#probleemForm').hide();` and if you want to show it again just change `hide()` to `show()`

for the message create something like `<div id="myMessage"/>`

then in `$('#myMessage').val("something went wrong")` this will keep the form open of course. If you want to close the form you can use a standard `@URl.Action` and redirect or you could just do a simple `Javascript alert('error messsage')`

Comment: And how can I prevent the json-question?

Comment: at what point do you receive the request to open json? is it on the return of true/false.

Comment: On the return. It is the result of my controller-action

Comment: Can you post your controller action. I'd expect to see it declared to return a JsonResult with something like `return new Json(false);`